Why jn:parse-json and parse-json give different results
I have following command :
echo '{"a":null}' | xidel -se '
  jn:parse-json($raw)/join((exists(a),a)),
     parse-json($raw)/join((exists(a),a))
'

the output is
true null
false

I know jn:parse-json is JSONiq extension.
Why are the results different ?
Is there a way to get internal representation of jn:parse-json($raw) and parse-json($raw), in order to understand difference in behaviour?

jn:parse-json is indeed JSONiq (deprecated), while fn:parse-json is XPath 3.1.

Looks a lot like my notes.

@Reino Indeed, it's from your notes. Could you answer the two questions?


Well, JSONiq is an extension to XQuery 1.0, while XPath 3.1 and newer have native JSON support. So, different rules and thus different results. 2. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "internal representation".


If we just output jn:parse-json($raw) and parse-json($raw), they both give the same result {"a":null}. Why appending /join((exists(a),a)) give different results ?

By internal representation, I meant following : if we do let $o1:=parse-json($raw), $o2:=jn:parse-json($raw) How can I see the difference between $o1 and $o2 ?

You can use serialize( parse-json($raw) , {"method": "adaptive"} )

@BeniBela Thank you for commenting! The idea is to understand the difference between jn:parse-json($raw) and parse-json($raw), and also which one should I use ?

Using parse-json($raw)  for parsing is more future-proof. Serialize shows what the differences are

@BeniBela Understood. But parse-json seems harder to work with, because, for example, echo '{"a":null}' | xidel -se 'jn:parse-json($raw)("a")' outputs null as expected whereas echo '{"a":null}' | xidel -se 'parse-json($raw)("a")' outputs nothing.
